# How to bind ObservableCollection to the ListView in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, observablecollection

I have the following xaml file:

```
<Page ...>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MissingValues}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Information on Missing Values">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Element.Name}" Header="Element" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Description" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Code behind is only:

```
DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

And `MyViewModel` has `public ObservableCollection<MissingValue> MissingValues` initialized in the constructor. On the button click, items are added to this property and everything works as exptected.

Since the xaml file became too big, i wanted to make it smaller and easier to manage by extracting this `ListView` in a `UserControl` called `MissingValuesListView` and invoking it using the following code:

```
<local:MissingValuesListView></local:MissingValuesListView>
```

However, the list is no longer updated when the new elements are added.

`MissingValuesListView`'s code behind contains only `DataContext = new MyViewModel();`.

I don't think it's of any relevance (since the code works when part of the main xaml file, but not when moved to UserControl), but both `MyViewModel` and `MissingValue` implment `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

My question is why is this not working? I assume i'm missing some code or some binding, but i failed to find out what. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Where is MissingValues? Are you sure it's got data in it? Did you somehow lose the itemssource binding when you moved the listview? What does this new usercontrol look like?

Comment: Do not set the UserControl's DataContext in its code behind (to a second view model instance). It will be inherited automatically from the Page. In general, a UserControl should never explicitly set its own DataContext. Its child elements either directly bind to an inherited DataContext, or to dependency properties that are exposed by the control.

Comment: @Clemens you are right, thanks! It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MissingValuesListView's code behind contains only `DataContext = new MyViewModel();`.

It shouldn't. Try to remove this line. You should simply copy the following XAML into `MissingValuesListView.xaml` and replace it with `<local:MissingValuesListView />` in the current XAML file:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MissingValues}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Information on Missing Values">
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Element.Name}" Header="Element" Width="100" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" Header="Description" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

If you do this, the `UserControl` will inherit the `DataContext` where the `MissingValues` property is defined from its parent element and the binding should work just like before.